# Azure Data Factory: Access token from MSI failed for Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-data-factory, azure-managed-identity

Details of the Error: Get access token from MSI failed for Datafactory XXXX, region XXXX. Please verify resource url is valid and retry. Details: Accquire MI token from MI store V1 failed.

Error Code: 2403

Failure type: User Configuration issue

---

used web activity in Azure Data Factory to access Azure function app using MSI

Comment: How did you configure the activity?

Comment: Actually i don't have knowledge on this Junas. ticked was raised to sort out the root cause on this

in  the web activity setting
URL: https://xxxx.azurewebsites.net/api/xxx?code=xxxx==
Method: POST
BODY:
Integration runtime: AutoResolveIntegrationRuntime
Authentication: MSI
Resource: https://xxxx.azurewebsites.net/

Comment: Well, it sounds like it is configured wrong. And without seeing how it is configured, I can't really help.

Answer (score 3):

I also had these kind of issues and it took me some time to figure out the right resource ID for the token I needed.
First of all the "Web-Activity" in ADF or Azure Synapse can be used for performing Azure REST-API calls quite good.

But we have to understand that "access token" is not always the same "access token". Azure AD provides different access token depending on the resource provider you want to access.
Here is a list of Resource IDs you can use:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/services-support-managed-identities#azure-services-that-support-azure-ad-authentication

Unfortunately it doesn't seem up to date, as I'm using in my case for `https://dev.azuresynapse.net` (which is not listed on the docs yet).

[image: Resouce ID example for synapse]

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, there is Azure Function activity in Azure Data Factory. You can try that.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-azure-function-activity